# Two different Java objects are always equal regardless of fields value

Tags: java, inheritance, equals, lombok

I have classes defined like below:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder

public abstract class A {
    private Enum myEnum;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder

public class KA extends A {
    private MyPackage pck;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
}
```

I tested them with the following code:

```
KA ka1 = new KA();
KA ka2 = new KA();
System.out.println("Object equal: " + ka1.equals(ka2));
```

For KA, either no-arg constructor or constructor with totally different arguments, I would get they are equal.

I want KA to be using the default equal method of Object class which is comparing the object memory addresses.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using lombok's @Data, it generates an .equals() method for your class based on the fields within the annotated class. I.e. the equals-method does not include the fields of the child class. Read the documentation of the annotation here: https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

Comment: ... class `KA` does not have `@Data`,  However, probably the first paste (defining `class A`) is supposed to be the `Aggregator` that `KA` extends. In which case it inherits that `equals` and thus, this is equal. @EzyHoo What you want is to override the behaviour of your parent class. So, do so: manually override `equals`, making it `return this == other;`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thx. It should be a A instead of Aggregator!

Comment: @rzwitserloot Wow. surprised to know that the overriden equal method is also inherited. Can u make your comment an answer?

Comment: U did get the question I guess. The Data is not in Child class.

Comment: Rather than inheriting a bad `equals` and replacing it with the default `equals`, you could consider removing the `@Data` annotation. That annotation is just an aggregate of other lombok-annotations, so you could instead include a set of lower level annotations. The documentation underlines which annotations `@Data` is the equivalent of.

Comment: @ODDMinus1 The `@Data` that would need to be removed is on `class Aggregator` - possibly not a class that OP can modify. Or they can, but it _should_ have a field-based equality concept. If it's the latter, OP is breaking all sorts of contracts with this reversion to `this == object`, of course. Point is, 'just remove `@Data`' is probably oversimplifying matters.

Comment: Of course, and it's thus good to have both options mentioned. But if `Aggregator` is a class OP can modify, it's good to know the implicit behavior of the annotation to be able to evaluate whether it's needed for that case. My point is that `@Data` is mostly useless on a field-less class, where most of its resulting behavior is what OP is explicitly trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Class `KA` inherits its equals method from `A`, which uses a field-based equality due to [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data).  Specifically, it returns true if the two instances have the same value for `myEnum` and are exactly the same class.

In order to get the same identity-based equality behavior matching [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), you'll need to override the equality methods in `KA` to have the desired behavior:

```java
public class KA extends A {
    private MyPackage pck;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return this == o;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return System.identityHashCode(this);
    }
}
```

Note that this will satisfy the equivalence relation required by [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).  Lombok's `equals` implementation is careful to ensure that objects of different classes are unequal.  Therefore, a `KA` will never equal a non-`KA` `A`, and vice versa.

Comment: Thx. Should the equals() method check equality for each field?

Comment: An `equals` method should check equality for each field that it wants to have be part of the determination of whether two instances are equal.  Often it'll be all fields.  Unless configured otherwise, Lombok's `@Data` uses all fields.